# How to get the value of href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

From source code:

```
<a class="nextinst" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" href="#401">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
```

I want to get `#401`

I have unsuccessfully tried

```
$('.nextinst').attr('href').val()  
$('.nextinst').attr('href').html()
$('.nextinst').attr('href').text()
```

After I recover it, I then want to check if the modal with that id has been loaded in the DOM.

Comment: just `$('.nextinst').attr('href')`?

Comment: Why the `val`, `html`, `text`? Just get the attribute, it will return the value

Comment: val = getting the value of the element, html= like innerHTML in native javascript, and text= is getting the text in the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of an attribute use `attr()`:

```
$('.nextinst').attr('href');
```

See example:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log($('.nextinst').attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="nextinst" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" href="#401">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add an ID for that element and call the `attr()` to get the attribute of href use the this:

```
  function clickIt(){
    var val = $("#linkHref").attr("href");
    alert(val);
  }
```

[image]